# How to make the same thickness for an object with different thickness?

Tags: objects

there is an object with different thickness, thicker on top, thinner on the bottom, but the thickness is not symmetrical, how to make the entire thickness of the object the same, to reset it roughly[image]

Comment: I guess you need to select a side and SY0 (or SX0) and same thing for the other side

Comment: ... on top of that, you should care the topology, that seems to be a source of issues (https://imgur.com/WHDaZzM)